# Error using entity framework to add rows to tables using foreign key relation

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I've written the following C# code:

```
        abcEntities entities = new abcEntities();            
        abc_Lids_New newUserEntry = new abc_Lids_New()
        {
            Lid = lid,
            FName = fname,
            LName = lname,
            Phone = phone,
        };
        newUserEntry.abc_class_Assignments_New = new System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<abc_class_Assignments_New>();
        foreach (string classId in classIds)
        {
            newUserEntry.abc_class_Assignments_New.Add(new abc_class_Assignments_New()
            {
                Lid = lid,
                classID = classId
            });
        }
        entities.abc_Lids_New.AddObject(newUserEntry);
        entities.SaveChanges();
```

The code is supposed to add a new row in abc_Lids_New representing a new user.  The code is also supposed to add rows in abc_class_assignments_new corresponding to the user's lid and a number of class ids.

However, I am getting an error: `Unable to update the EntitySet 'UCV_TF_Assignments_New' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.`

Up until recently, I had only used the Entity Framework with stored procedures, so this is something new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EntitySet` "'UCV_TF_Assignments_New" is either based on a `View` (in which case, you have to create the `InsertFunction` (stored procedure)) or it lacks a Primary Key (in which case, add one).

Comment: I noticed that I mixed up my fake acronyms - sorry about that :-/

Comment: I have set LID as the primary key in `abc_Lids_new` and LID as a foreign key in `abc_tf_Assignments_New`.  Is there something else I must do?

Comment: In the EDMX view, right click, and update the model from the database

Comment: What a rookie mistake on my part - I forgot to update the model.